# Work around for calendar LVWP recurrence?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, calendar, recurring-events

Is there any type of work around for recurrence issue for calendars? Everything I seem to find online about the topic leads me to believe that there isn't but its worth asking the experts! :)

I am interested in having any type of web part that can display today's events, including those that were created prior but an instance of the occurence includes today. I cannot seem to find a solution to this anywhere.

The most I can develop with is javascript COM, SPD (no VS). :/

Anyone know of any work arounds?

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the OOB SharePoint Web Services. See detailed walk through here:

[Use SPServices to Get Recurring Events as Distinct Items](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Use-SPServices-to-Get-Recurring-Events-as-Distinct-Items.aspx)

Comment: Can we do this for the web list also? Or only accessible in the app model only?